# The value of length when replacing space with %20

Tags: java

I am working on a problem of replacing spaces with `%20` from Cracking the Coding Interview 5th edition:

> Write a method to replace all spaces in a string with '%20'. You may assume that the string has sufficient space at the end of the string to hold the additional characters, and that you are given the "true" length of the string. (Note: if implementing in Java, please use a character array so that you can perform this operation in place)

The algorithm I have is:

```
public static void replaceSpaces(String input, int length) {

    char[] str = input.toCharArray();

    int spaceCount = 0;
    for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(str[i] == ' ') {
            spaceCount++;
        }
    }

    int newLength = length + spaceCount * 2;

    str[newLength] = '\0';

    for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(str[i] == ' ') {
            str[newLength - 1] = '0';
            str[newLength - 2] = '2';
            str[newLength - 3] = '%';
            newLength = newLength - 3;
            System.out.println(str);
        } else {
            str[newLength - 1] = str[i];
            newLength = newLength - 1;
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Printing out each step of the function, here are my outputs:

```
Mr John Smith   h
Mr John Smith  th
Mr John Smith ith
Mr John Smithmith
Mr John SmitSmith
Mr John S%20Smith
Mr John n%20Smith
Mr Johnhn%20Smith
Mr Johohn%20Smith
Mr JoJohn%20Smith
Mr%20John%20Smith
Mr%20John%20Smith
Mr%20John%20Smith
```

I have two questions:

1. We know the new length of the string is `17`. What I do not understand is, why we need to have `[newLength - 1]` instead of `[newLength]`. We are interested in replacing the current index, no? Or is it because the new length is 17, but when converted to indices, it's actually 16 (0th index).
2. What is the purpose of: `str[newLength] = '\0';`

Comment: In C, "strings" are null-terminated.  Maybe this code is an overly-direct port?

Comment: Just to be sure: you know that you could use 'String.replace(" ", "%20");' instead, right?

Comment: @Tom It's an interview question - I wish I could do that during an interview.

Comment: Q2 I ask myself. Where is this algorithm from? As you ask about how it works, I doubt it's yours. This would be valuable for us to both judge your question and help you.

Comment: @azurefrog I removed that line and the function still works..

Comment: @SillyFreak It's from "Cracking the Code Interview" for string manipulation

Comment: Yeah, because in java Strings have an actual length, rather than being a char* with a null terminator.  I would expect that in Java that statement would throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Guess: the length parameter tells you how many chars of the original String actually matter? Is `newLength` always equal to `input.length()`?

Comment: Actually I see several errors in that code.  You can't just decide you have a new array length in Java and then start accessing those locations, you need to instantiate a new array.  How did you get it to run?

Comment: @Andreas Congratulations on saying a lot, but at the same time, saying nothing substantial at all. What can be improved? What's wrong with it? Considering this is exactly the reason why I am asking the question, I'm not sure what your answer really solves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't all have that book, but from a pending edit, I see that the exact question is:

> Write a method to replace all spaces in a string with '%20'. You may assume that the string has sufficient space at the end of the string to hold the additional characters, and that you are given the "true" length of the string. (Note: **if implementing in Java, please use a character array so that you can perform this operation in place**)

*From Cracking the Coding Interview 5th edition*

---

So, it says that your `input` argument should be a `char[]`.

Since you're changing the length of the text, your method would need to return the new length.

---

*Question 1:*

> We know the new length of the string is 17. What I do not understand is, why we need to have [newLength - 1] instead of [newLength]. We are interested in replacing the current index, no? Or is it because the new length is 17, but when converted to indices, it's actually 16 (0th index).

You answered it yourself. With a length of 17, the indices are 0 to 16. If the array is only 17 long, accessing index 17 with throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

*Question 2:*

> What is the purpose of: str[newLength] = '\0';

None whatsoever. It's is invalid and has no purpose in Java. Remove it.

Java Strings have a `length()`. In C, strings are zero-terminated, but not in Java.

---

To test the code, try running it with this:

```
char[] buffer = { 'M','r',' ','J','o','h','n',' ','S','m','i','t','h','*','*','*','*' };
int inLen = 13;
System.out.println("buffer: '" + new String(buffer) + "'");
System.out.println("inLen : " + inLen);
System.out.println("input : '" + new String(buffer, 0, inLen) + "'");
int outLen = replaceSpaces(buffer, inLen);
System.out.println("outLen: " + outLen);
System.out.println("result: '" + new String(buffer, 0, outLen) + "'");
```

Output should be:

```
buffer: 'Mr John Smith****'
inLen : 13
input : 'Mr John Smith'
outLen: 17
result: 'Mr%20John%20Smith'
```

Accessing `input[17]` in the method would throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

Here is one possible implementation based on the shown code, that follows the quoted text, and stop processing once all spaces are replaced.

```
public static int replaceSpaces(char[] str, int length) {
    int spaceCount = 0;
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            spaceCount++;
    int shift = spaceCount * 2;
    int newLength = length + shift;
    for (int i = newLength - 1; shift > 0; i--) {
        char c = str[i - shift];
        if (c != ' ') {
            str[i] = c;
        } else {
            str[i] = '0';
            str[--i] = '2';
            str[--i] = '%';
            shift -= 2;
        }
    }
    return newLength;
}
```

This produces the expected output from the test code above.

Comment: But `str[newLength] = '\0'` is accessing that index, so it isn't out of bounds. This solution is actually from the book: https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci/blob/master/java/Chapter%201/Question1_4/Question.java

Comment: @Zar I don't know what that referenced code is, but it is *not* a correct answer to the problem *in Java*. Java don't terminate text with `\0`, and the question doesn't say anything about it having to, so *for Java*, the code is wrong.

Comment: If you look at the account that made the repo, it is the author of the book. I agree that it works without that line, my personal solution doesn't use it. But it is still a valid thing to do, and if you run the code in the repo it works. I'm just wondering why she chose to do that.

Comment: @Zar It only works in the code because the array was deliberately oversized with a ` + 1` to make room for the meaningless `\0`. If you run the test code I showed, which follows the quoted text, it will fail.

Comment: "it is still a valid thing to do". Not really, if you convert the char array back to String, you'll have an invisible character at the end, and a length one greater than the actual length. That's hardly expected by the user of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Code posted below works good. Cheers.
[***Sample Output***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Egq.png)

```
 package StringAndArray;


 public class Question_Four_Replace_Spaces {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "Mr Shubham Dilip Yeole";
    char[] array = string.toCharArray();
    System.out.println("\n\nInput : " +string);
    System.out.println("\n\nResult: "+method_1(array,string.length()));
    method_1(array,string.length());
 }


private static String method_1(char[] array, int length) {
    int spaceCount = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]==' ') spaceCount++;
    }
    int count = 0;
    int newLength = length + spaceCount*2;
    char[] newArray = new char[newLength];

    for(int i= 0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]==' '){
            newArray[count++] = '%';
            newArray[count++] = '2';
            newArray[count++] = '0';
        }else{
            newArray[count] = array[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    String newString1 = new String(newArray);

    return newString1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your direct questions have been answered in the comments, so here instead I will focus on issues with the method as written.

Ignoring the fact that this functionality already exists in the base `String` class (and many other 3rd party string utility classes), we can still write a basic string replacement function.  The function as written in the question does not appear to be written for Java, and does not return any value, which since Strings are immutable means that the function cannot possibly be fulfilling its name.

Instead, we need to create a new array which we copy the existing characters to while replacing any spaces we encounter with %20.  We then return this array as a new `String`.  Conveniently, Java has a class which encapsulates a variable size array of characters that we can use to assemble our new String called `StringBuilder`.

So a simpler and working (but not optimized) replacement function in Java may look like:

```
public static String replaceSpaces(String input)
{
    if (input == null) return null;

    // New string builder with some padding to account for replacements...
    // Padding was chosen pretty arbitrarily, there are certainly better values.
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.length() + 128);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = input.chatAt(i);
        if (c == ' ') {
            builder.append("%20");
        } else {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

It may be more optimal to convert the entire String to a `char[]` at the beginning, and iterate over the array instead of using `String.charAt(i)`.  And we could probably choose a more appropriate padding for the `StringBuilder` by multiplying the length of the existing string by some constant based on the expected number of spaces.  For very large strings it could even make sense to first count the number of spaces before declaring our array, but those optimizations are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Shouldn't you append `c` in the else statement instead of a space? Your solution is actually much more clean and I can't believe I did not think of it. That said, I won't be able to use this if they do not allow the usage of anything but the basic data structures.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Yes, you are right!  My bad, I never tested this and just wrote it right in the text area.  Good catch, solution has been edited.

Comment: Judging by this.. Your solution should be `O(n)` since you just make a clean pass through the array and adding elements as necessary?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Yes, O(n) (well, subject to array resizing).  However, per the edit to the question that has been made, this is not a solution for an in place replacement.

Comment: This is not a valid solution for the actual interview question (now edited into the original question).

Comment: @Zar Indeed, see my comment that is just above yours.  At the time this answer was written, however, there was no in place requirement stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test public void replaceTest() {
    String s = "Mr John Smith      ";
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    int length = 13;
    char[] chars1 = subString(chars, length);
    //actualString = actualString.replace(" ", "%20");
    Assert.assertEquals(replace(chars1, "%20"), "Mr%20John%20Smith");
  }

  private char[] subString(char[] chars, int length) {
    char[] newChar = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      newChar[i] = chars[i];
    }

    return newChar;
  }

  private String replace(char[] chars, String s) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      if (chars[i] == ' ') {
        builder.append(s);
      } else {
        builder.append(chars[i]);
      }
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String urlify(String s1, int truelength) {
        int countspaces = 0;
        char[] charobj = s1.toCharArray();
        for (int i = truelength - 1; i < charobj.length; i++) {
            if (charobj[i] == ' ') {
                countspaces++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = truelength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (charobj[i] == ' ' && countspaces != 0) {
                for (int j = truelength - 1; j > i; j--) {
                    char temp = charobj[j];
                    charobj[j + 2] = temp;


                }
                countspaces = countspaces - 2;
                charobj[i] = '%';
                charobj[i + 1] = '2';
                charobj[i + 2] = '0';
                truelength = truelength + 2;

            }
        }


        return String.valueOf(charobj);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).